# Tool for creating system image from DOS (should be USB bootable) ..?

Tags: backup, bootable-media, disk-image, disk-operating-system

I want to know if there's any decent tool which can be used to create the system image from DOS .. What I specifically want to do is to put the program in my FAT32 formatted USB, then boot the target computer from the USB so that the tool runs, and then it should be able to create a complete system image of the entire system, and store it on the USB itself ..

Please note that I can ONLY do this from boot time because of other limitations .. I cannot go into any OS to do it from there .. So I need tools which can do this at boot time from DOS ..

Comment: any specific reason it needs to be dos? clonezilla fulfills your other needs other than being dos based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) it has a lot of backup tools. [Here](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk) are the instructions to make put it on bootable usb

Comment: Actually I used the Ultimate Boot CD and it seems to be working for me .. but the idea is the same :)

Comment: I'm glad you've made it. :)